# forward slash replacement in awk

Tags: awk

I started to learn awk. Here I am trying to produced a formatted list of all song albums in a directory which have many sub-directories(year ranges). But the last gsub replacement is not removing forward slash. I know it can be done using many ways using bash utilities like sed. But I would like to learn why this is not working in awk.

```
lst=$(mktemp)
find . | grep -vE "\.mp3|\.sh|\."$ > $lst #| tee $lst
gawk -F"/" '{
if(NF>2){
gsub(".tar.gz","",$3)
gsub(".zip","",$3)
gsub(".ZIP","",$3)
gsub("/","",$3)
print $3
}
else
print$0
}' $lst
exit 0
```

Comment: Note that you are missing a space between `print` and `$0` in `print$0`

Comment: Also you have `$` after the double quotes in `grep -vE "\.mp3|\.sh|\."$ > $lst`.. Or maybe this will be part of the regex to `grep`?

Comment: What extension do the song album files have? If it is `.mp3`, why do you grep `grep -vE "\.mp3|\.sh|\."$` ?

Comment: You need a parenthesis around your regex, like `"(\.mp3|\.sh|\.)$"`, if not, the `$` will only match on the last alternation (that is `\.$` and you will also exlude files like `a.mp3.gz`..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You used "`/`" as a field separator therefore `$3` will never have "`/`".

Answer (score 2):

This works fine:

```
echo "test/more" | awk '{gsub("/","",$0)}1'
testmore
```

So it may be some other wrong in your code.

### Post input data, and how you like your output data.

Try using regex.

```
echo "test/more" | awk '{gsub(/\//,"",$0)}1'
testmore
```

`gsub(regexp, replacement [, target])`

Comment: The OP used `-F"/"` option in his `gawk` command. That make it a field separator therefore `$3` will not have any `/`.

Comment: @Jotne Yes input data and expected output would be nice :)

Comment: @alvits I did see that after I have added the answer :)

Answer (score 2):

You can simplify your script (my opinion) as follows:

```
find . | awk '
!/(\.mp3|\.sh|\.)$/ {
    n=split($0,a,"/")
    if(n>2){
        sub(".tar.gz","",a[3])
        sub(".zip","",a[3])
        gsub(".ZIP","",a[3])
        print a[3]
    }
    else
        print $0
}'
```